# Flutter tts delayed by few seconds to speech starts

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

I am using `flutter_tts` for voice notifications. But speech delayed by 4 to 6 seconds for different languages(Indian languages). Is it known issue or can any one suggest the best approach?

below is the sample code,

```
//get the available voices
  static void getAvailableVoiceData(String selectedVoiceLanguage, RemoteNotification? notification) async {
    switch(selectedVoiceLanguage) {
      case "English":
        languageCode = "en-US";
        break;
      case "हिंदी":
        languageCode = "hi-IN";
        break;
      default:
        languageCode = "kn-IN";
    }

    //get all the available voice language for the device
    List<Object?> voices = await ftts.getVoices;
    var availableVoices = voices.cast<Map>().map((e) => e.cast<String,String>()).toList();
    var selectedVoice = availableVoices.firstWhere((element) => element['locale']!.contains(languageCode));
    //check the language is available for the device
    bool isLanguageAvailable = await ftts.isLanguageAvailable(selectedVoice['locale']!);
    //if language is available, then play the voice message
    if(isLanguageAvailable) {
          translator.translate("${notification?.body}", to: selectedVoice['locale']!.split("-")[0]).then((translationText) async {
            await ftts.setVolume(1.0);
            await ftts.setPitch(1);

            ftts.setVoice(selectedVoice);
            ftts.setLanguage(selectedVoice['locale']!);
            await ftts.speak(translationText.text);
          });
        }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue, some languages in special, or even some voices, take longer to generate the speech than others. I filtered out all voices that cointained 'network'on then (for android's google. So yes, I think a few languages, and and some voices, take longer than others to process TTS.